# cp command simply not copying

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I am working on a shell script and for some reason when I say

```
cp full_path/* full_path_directory/
```

I get an error. I have echoed out the command and when I run what it echos in an interactive shell it works. I can't figure out why it won't work in a shell script. I'm using full paths rather than absolute. I have tried to putting a slash at the end of the destination directory and then not putting a slash...what else could it be?

Error:

```
cp: /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/baseline/*: No such file or directory
```

So when I echo it out I get:

```
/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/baseline/* /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/test/
```

Comment: What's the exact command you typed to get that error?

Comment: post the exact command line; also what is the output of ls -al on that baseline directory?

Comment: @Kevin: `cp -r` is only needed to copy recursively - which is, maybe, not needed. However - if this was the goal, there wouldn't be that errormessage. Who voted this up?

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says. There are no files in `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/baseline/` directory, or you don't have permissions to read the directory. What does `ls` show you?

Comment: there are files in there. Looking at the files they are -rw-r--r-- but I am running the script as root...I say sudo when I run my script.

Comment: what are the permissions on the directory itself? `ls -ld ...`

Comment: @Bohemian Not true. The OP specifically said "shell script". and also gives an echo command from the shell.

Comment: I thought the shell script would do whatever an interactive shell would do. So if it echoed out something it would do exactly that in the shell script. Apparently it did literally take the asterisk as that being a filename.

Comment: Default shell behavior is to expand the wildcard, but if it cannot be expanded (no matches) it gives it literally (with the wildcards) to the program.An echo should have shown you all matches. Since it didn',t it is another indication that there are no files matching.